# Determine the common difference for the arithmetic series given $s_n$ and $a$

Tags: sequences-and-series, arithmetic

I've been given the values $s_{11}=682$ and $a=17$.  I need to find the common difference, $d$.

I've tried using a bunch of different equations, but I'm not sure which on is the right one.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Yoou should show what you tried.

Answer (score 2):

$S_{n} = \frac{a_{1}+a_{n}}{2}\cdot n$, where $a_{n} = a_{1}+d(n-1)$.
It's easy to find $d = \frac{2S_{n}-2na_{1}}{n(n-1)}$

Comment: What would a1 and an be?

Comment: @Grimestock I guess , $a$ is the first member of your arithmetic series.

Comment: So $a = a_{1}$.

Comment: Would the answer be -3.2?

Comment: I think the expression for $d$ is missing an $n$: $$d = \frac{2S_{n}-2na_{1}}{n(n-1)}$$

Comment: @nickgard I guess you're right!

Comment: @nickgard Thank you! Is there an equation I can use to find n?

Comment: @Grimestock:  the question tells you $n=11$

Comment: @nickgard Would d=9?   By using the formulas you provided?

Comment: @Grimestock Yes, d=9 is correct.